# Dosage values are not passing correct through validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm coding a function to validate if a number is a valid dosage. A valid dosage is given by value from 0 to 100 (inclusive range). It looks simple, but there are 3 conditions:

- The value is not required, so empty value should return true;
- There can exist one optional '%' percent sign at the end;
- Decimal places are also optional.

I think I am close to the final function, but there are one test where my function fails, and I don't understand why:

```
function checkDosage(originalValue) {
    var validDosage, isNumeric,
        value = originalValue;

    isNumeric = function(num) {
        return !isNaN(num);
    }

    // take off percent sign if exists
    if (value.slice(-1) == '%') {
        value = value.slice(0, -1);
    }

    // get numeric value
    value = parseFloat(value);

    // check if it is really a number
    isNumeric = isNumeric(value);

    // conditional for dosage
    validDosage = value >= 0 && value <= 100;

    // treatment
    if (!originalValue || isNumeric && validDosage) {
        return true; // valid
    }
    return false; // invalid
}

checkDosage('');       // true
checkDosage('0');      // true
checkDosage('%');      // true
checkDosage('-1%');    // false
checkDosage('10.5%');  // true
checkDosage('10%%');   // true ??????? THIS SHOULD BE FALSE
checkDosage('100%');   // true
checkDosage('101%');   // false
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using `parseFloat`, which discards any trailing characters it finds.

Instead, use `Number(string)` which will either return you a number or the value `NaN` (not a number). Then your `isNumeric` function can be replaced by a call to the built in function `isNaN`

Comment: Not at all.

`parseFloat('10%'); /* 10 */` but `Number('10%') /* NaN */`

Answer (score 0):

You're merely checking if the string ends with a `%`. You aren't checking that there is exactly zero or one `%`s.

In your percent sign logic, you could do something like this:

```
if (value.slice(-1) === '%') {
  value = value.slice(0, -1);
  if (value.slice(-1) === '%') {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will chop off the percent sign. If there's still a percent sign at the end of the string, then that means there was more than one `%`. So this fails your validation, return `false`.

EDIT: The reason your existing logic doesn't catch the double `%` is because if the string was `10%%`, and you chopped off the last `%`, then it'd be `10%`. If you call `parseFloat('10%')`, you'll get back 10, which passes your `isNumeric` test.

Comment: I think I got it, but what if it was `('10p%')`?

Comment: Or you could do `while (value.slice(-1) === '%') { removeSign; }`. Then once that is done either `parseInt` the result to make sure you have an integer or validate the string is numeric before moving on. This way you are making sure all percent signs are removed before proceeding with calculations.

Comment: I think it would pass `'10%%%'` for sure, but the user can input `'10p%10'` as well and it will continue returning true, I think the real problem is in the `isNumeric` test as you said, but I don't know what exactly